# changing background color of a field for three second with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am new to jquery. I have a simple form which has four field:Username is Required and must be 4 – 8 characters in length,Birthdate must be a date, Email address is required - must be a valid email address and Home page which must be a valid URL.I have wrote this part in the following code.

**Now here is my question:** I want to add a code that "**Whenever a rule gets broken

for a field in my form, that field must have a yellow background color applied to it for three seconds; then it changes back to the original white.**"do you have any idea? I really appreciate your help.

```
$('form').validate();
$("#username").rules("add",{
minlength: 4,maxlength: 8,
messages:{
required: "Required input",minlength: jQuery.format("must be 4-8 characters")}
});
```

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question, other than the implied "can somebody please do my homework for me?" - which part are you stuck on, the changing colours or the three-second delay? Just to confirm, and bearing in mind that jQuery _is_ JavaScript and therefore you can't use jQuery without using JavaScript, does "use jQuery not with JavaScript" mean use jQuery methods only, i.e., use jQuery animation methods like `.delay()` rather than directly coding it with `setTimeout()`?

Comment: jQuery is javascript? jQuery UI has a highlight function that might suit you just fine!

Comment: first of all I don't know how to get the result from validation function to  change their background.As I told before I am new to jquery I am asking for help to learn and appreciate your helps

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').validate().submit(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
          $(this).find('.error').removeClass('error');
     }, 3000);
});
```

validate and submit do not have to be on the same chain, but the idea is you set a timeout from the submit event to remove the error state.

```
$('form').validate({
      invalidHandler : function(form){
           setTimeout(function(){
               $(form).find('.error').removeClass('error');
           }, 3000);
      }
})
```

Comment: Fresheyeball ,Thanks a lot for your time.I tried your code. It gives a yellow background color to the Text fields which are not being filled in correctly, but the timer does not work. I even tried setInterval instead of setTimeout. But still not working.Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: the timer not working may be evidence that the submit function is not working. Can you validate that the function is running. You may also want to try placing your time as the submit handler. I have edited my answer to include that option.

Answer (score 0):

To get the invalid fields to have a yellow background color add to your css:

```
.error{
    background: yellow;
}
```

`.error` is the class name given to the invalid fields when a form is validated. As for the timeout to change the background back to white, I've been trying for a while with no luck. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Marjorie Franklin thanks for your time, I am working on the code that Fresheyeball has posted.It changes the background color of the  Text fields which are not being filled in correctly, but the timer does not work.